# PHP remove element data from transformer

Tags: php, laravel

I have this object from transfomers:

```
{
"lists": [
  {
    "product": {
      "id": "642c1986-c383-4710-8412-3b9c80ab461e",
      "parent_category_id": "38da81a7-2507-4fcf-be0b-aff7c4808737",
      "category_id": "6a00814c-c2ea-4cd1-9414-e622c4196c45",
      "name": "Skinny",
      "description": "Skinny",
      "image": "",
      "listings": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "cffc889f-41d5-40eb-8fc3-f64c157d748d",
            "price": "112.00",
            "merchant": {
              "id": "054763eb-a1ae-44d1-8a25-77e5dfc2cd52",
              "name": "Example"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "product": {
      "id": "d9488bc9-0df3-4eab-a39f-634e34334261",
      "parent_category_id": "38da81a7-2507-4fcf-be0b-aff7c4808737",
      "category_id": "6a00814c-c2ea-4cd1-9414-e622c4196c45",
      "name": "Raw",
      "description": "Raw",
      "image": "",
      "listings": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "b3b4416b-7936-417f-afb3-03b7368bebfb",
            "price": "112.00",
            "merchant": {
              "id": "054763eb-a1ae-44d1-8a25-77e5dfc2cd52",
              "name": "Example"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

}

Inside similars > product there is listing object. I want to remove "data" key but keep the collection.

I've tried using foreach but not working:

```
foreach ($transformSimilar as $key => $row) {
    $transformSimilar[$key]['product']['listings'] = $transformSimilar[$key]['product']['listings']['data'];
}
```

Is there any better solution to achieve this?

Comment: You just want to bring `data` one level up? Why do you think the current method is bad?

Comment: @PEMapModder if the data is more than 1 it will become very slow to use foreach. and my foreach is fail.

Comment: But I don't see how faster it can be. Consider using `array_map` though?

Comment: If you are parsing data from JSON, you may want to use objects (second parameter of `json_decode` to be `false`). It would hopefully be faster.

Comment: @PEMapModder my foreach always return me `Undefined index: product`

Answer (score 0):

solve it:

```
foreach ($transform['lists'] as $key => $row) {
   $transform['lists'][$key]['product']['listings'] = $row['product']['listings']['data'];
}
```